# The SQLiteOpenHelper  onCreate(), always creates the database when it runs?

Tags: android, sqlite

Greetings,

I'm looking in the documentation for SQLite on Android but can't seem to find the anser for my question - so maybe someone here can help.

When I create a database using the SQLiteOpenHelper will the database only be created once if it does not exist or will it be overwritten each time I call the OnCreate method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be created once if it does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually want to call the `onCreate()` yourself... the helper will do it for you. But yes, it'll only be created once.

If you check out the [Notepad example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) in your local copy of the SDK (`SDK/platforms/android-1.6/samples/NotePad`) the `com.example.android.notepad.NotePadProvider` class has a full example.